# Problema al serializar y realizar una petición POST desde VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, serialización

Necesito enviar un objeto "JSON" (conservando el tipo string) desde VB.NET:

> json[{"id":1406,"proveedor":230,"escala":"ejemplo","cant":0},...{..}].

Tengo una `list<T>` la cual serializo (he intentado de varias formas, una de ellas: `JavaScriptSerializer`). El problema que tengo es que, uno de los valores del objeto es de tipo `string` (**escala**) y al parecer es dicho valor el que no me permite ejecutar la acción como quiero. Cuando quito ese valor de objeto (lo dejo `null`) si envío la petición, sin embargo, cuando le asigno un valor ya no me deja enviarlo.

¿Alguien sabe cual es el problema que hay serializar un string en VB.NET? ¿Podrían sugerir otra forma? ¡Gracias de antemano!

**Código:**

**Serialización:**

```
Dim serializer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim jsonEnvio = serializer.Serialize(listaMinimos)
```

**Envio:**

```
 Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(urlBase & urlAdd), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim postData = parametros
        Dim Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData)

        request.Method = method
        request.ContentType = contentType
        request.ContentLength = Data.Length
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", headerAuthorization)

        Using stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
        End Using

        Dim response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Dim responseString = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

        Return responseString
```

Comment: no hay ningun problema. Podes proveernos el codigo y como lo estas haciendo y tu objeto para que podamos ver si hay algo mal?

Comment: Edité la pregunta, alli está el código. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Por cierto, en la sección de envio, parametros es el JSON

Comment: Yo uso newtonsoft + HttpClient y no he tenido ese tipo de problemas. Intenta averiguar primero la exception.